# High degree polynom divisibility

Tags: polynomials

The problem is:

Show that $x^{44}+x^{33}+x^{22}+x^{11}+1$ is divisible by $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$

I am not sure how to approach this problem so any help would be very appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you mean $x^{44}+x^{33}+x^{22}+x^{11}+1$?

Comment: Yes, I did. Thank you for noticing.

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

Both are in Geometric Series

$$1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4=\frac{1-x^5}{1-x}$$ and $$1+x^{11}+x^{22}+x^{33}+x^{44}=\frac{1-x^{55}}{1-x^{11}}$$

So, $$\frac{1+x^{11}+x^{22}+x^{33}+x^{44}}{1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4}=\frac{(1-x^{55})(1-x)}{(1-x^{11})(1-x^5)}$$

Now using [Prove that $\gcd(a^n - 1, a^m - 1) = a^{\gcd(n, m)} - 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7473/prove-that-gcdan-1-am-1-a-gcdn-m-1),

$1-x^{55}$ is divisible by $1-x^5,1-x^{11}$ and

$(1-x^{11},1-x^5)=1-x$

Comment: You need more than just that to do it this way, e.g. see Andre's more complete sketch. But it is much easier by modular arithmetic - see my answer.

Comment: @BillDubuque, please find the edited answer

Comment: That's better. It is important to explicitly mention the required coprimality since many students overlook that essential point.

Answer (score 2):

${\rm mod} \dfrac{(x^5\!-\!1)}{(x\!-\!1)}:\,\ \color{#c00}{x^5\equiv 1}\,\Rightarrow\,x^{11n}\equiv x^n (\color{#c00}{x^5})^{2n}\equiv x^n\Rightarrow\,x^{44}\!+\!x^{33}\!+\cdots+1\equiv x^4\!+\!x^3\!+\cdots+1\equiv 0$

Comment: Thank you, this really is a rather clear and nice answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is not hard to see that $x^5-1$ divides $x^{55}-1$.

Thus $(x-1)(x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)$ divides $(x^{11}-1)(x^{44}+x^{33}+x^{22}+x^{11}+1)$ and therefore

$x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ divides $(x^{10}+x^9+\cdots +x+1)( x^{44}+x^{33}+x^{22}+x^{11}+1)$.

But $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ and $x^{10}+x^9+\cdots +x+1$ are relatively prime (use the Euclidean Algorithm).

The result follows.

Answer (score 0):

Try plain polynomial long division. If it gives you trouble, try it with a smaller example like $x^4-2x^3+4x^2-x+7$ divided by $x^2-3$.

In your original problem, you should find the quotient to be....

> $x^{40}-x^{39}+x^{35}-x^{34}+x^{30}-x^{28}+x^{25}-x^{23}+x^{20}-x^{17}+x^{15}-x^{12}+x^{10}-x^6+x^5-x+1$

Comment: I thought about this, but wondered if there was a more "elegant" way to do it. Thank you anyway though.

Comment: Indeed, this is an easy way to do it. Given the polynomials are simple, the division goes quickly. However, lab bhattacharjee's answer may provide a shorter way. It's certainly true and may indeed yield a much faster answer! However, I have yet to see how it gets you there faster. But it's certainly worth a strong look!

Comment: There is a very short way: compute the remainder only (we don't need the quotient) by using modular arithmetic. This yields a simple one-line proof - see my answer. @suomynona too.